# Add click event in code

Tags: ios, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a problem with add click event in my code.

On the main uiview I have added some subview(uiview) in code:

```
UIView *btnContainer = [UIView new];
iconButton.origin.x = (indexOfIcon % rowCount + 1) * leftPadding + (indexOfIcon % rowCount) * iconButton.size.width;
iconButton.origin.y = (rowIndex + 1) * topPadding + rowIndex * iconButton.size.height;
CGRect btnRect = iconButton;
btnContainer.frame = btnRect;
btnContainer.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:74/255.0 green:174/255.0 blue:223/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor];
btnContainer.layer.borderWidth = 1;
btnContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
[parent addSubview: btnContainer];
```

Now I want to add click to subview(uiview):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(goToReport:)];
[btnContainer addGestureRecognizer: tapGesture];
```

This is the delegate, but it does not do anything:

```
- (void) goToReport: (UIView *)sender
```

When I click the subview(uiview), why does it throw this exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType goToReport:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x788e46e0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean the delegate? 
Please make sure in the correct place of your implementation. I tried your code perfectly worked.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *btnContainer = [UIView new];
    CGRect btnRect = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50);
    btnContainer.frame = btnRect;
    btnContainer.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:74/255.0 green:174/255.0 blue:223/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor];
    btnContainer.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    btnContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
    [self.view addSubview: btnContainer];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(goToReport:)];
    [btnContainer addGestureRecognizer: tapGesture];
}

- (void) goToReport: (UIView *)sender {
    NSLog(@"tapped");
}

@end
```

Though, agree with @aeskreis your usage is not recommended.

Comment: many thanks, i found the issue is in goToReport.

Answer (score 1):

There are two primary issues here that are causing you to trip up.

1) The parameter to your gesture recognizer method should be the UIGestureRecognizer, not the UIView it is attached to.  You can access the view by using the "view" property of the recognizer.  Example:

```
- (void)someRecognizerCallback:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    View *myView = recognizer.view; // This is my view
}
```

2) I would not recommend using a gesture recognizer in this situation.  Rather, I would recommend using a UIButton, and using the method [UIButton addTarget:action:forControlEvent:].  An example usage would be:

```
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

If you are dead set on using a UIView (because maybe you have custom controls or some other reason), then try fixing your parameter type on your callback selector and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: thanks, because i need create a button, it's top is a image and bottom is a label, i don't know how to create a button like this.